# Nested If Then Statements follow hyperlink VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA and trying to use a series of userforms to generate a URL that fills out a separate webform. The webform will be filled in with the information entered into the userform. The 'WEBSITE' is a link to a pre-populated webform template.

I'm having some issues with nesting the If Then statements to trigger the URL generation. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
If (UserForm1.Tier1 = True Or UserForm1.Tier2 = True) And UserForm1B.CheckBoxN = True Then
    If UserFormN.ComboBoxNPT = January And UserFormN.ComboBoxNPG >= 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("WEBSITE" & "Vendor Name: " & UserForm1.ComboBoxVN.Value & "%0A" & UserFormN.Label119.Caption & ": " & UserFormN.ComboBoxNPG.Value)
    ElseIf UserFormN.ComboBoxNPT = January And UserFormN.ComboBoxNPS >= 1 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("WEBSITE" & "Vendor Name: " & UserForm1.ComboBoxVN.Value & "%0A" & UserFormN.Label120.Caption & ": " & UserFormN.ComboBoxNPS.Value)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: January should be in double-quotes if you are testing the value of the combobox against a string. If you will have a statement for each month, I suggest using a `Select Case` statement instead, it's quite a bit cleaner. That being said, your question isn't specific enough about what the parameters are. With more information, I might suggest the nesting is unnecessary, but I can't say for sure right now.

Comment: Thanks, adding the quotes made it fire. Yes, basically, I have a different URL for each month so I'll look into the Select Case statement.

Comment: I have 60 different packages and each package has 3 levels. If the customer is tier 1 or tier 2, then each selected package opens its own URL which will be populated by the userform content.

Comment: Sometimes the URL is associated with the time of the year (e.g, in the above, the customer has selected January, so it will open the January URL). If it is a Tier 3 customer that selects January, it will go to a different URL. Now, for a specific package, I've built in logic to test which package levels are selected as identified by the combobox containing a non-zero value next to a label of the package level, e,g, 'platinum'.

Comment: If the package is selected, then I will have the URL concatenated with that selection to fill out some of the webform, e.g. the webform's 'description' text box will say 'Platinum' and 'Package A' if it those were selected in the user form). It seems like there must be a more straightforward way to test these layers of conditions so I have less code to write, but I haven't found a better solution than writing it in a nested If Then statement yet. @MoondogsMaDawg

Comment: Gotcha, I think that's a perfect case to build an object class but that's probably too deep if you are just starting with vba. Nesting isn't a big deal, it's just harder to read and maintain. Based on your comments, I think your first `If` block is fine (even if you need to add a bunch of elses), but I think a nested `Select Case` can clean up the rest when dealing with months. It looks like a well-defined hierarchy anyway, so keep it up!